# Is there a serverless kubernetes datadog agent?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, datadog

I have a unique type of Kubernetes cluster that cannot install the [Kubernetes Datadog agent](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/?tab=helm). I would like to collect the logs of individual docker containers in my Kubernetes pods similar to how the [Docker agent](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/docker/log/?tab=containerinstallation#one-step-install) works.

I am currently collecting docker logs from Kubernetes and then using a script with the [Datadog custom log forwarder](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/?tab=http#custom-log-forwarder) to upload them to Datadog.  I was curious if there is a better way to achieve this serverless collection of docker logs from Kubernetes clusters in datadog?  The ideal situation I want is to plug my kubeconfig somewhere and then let Datadog take care of the rest without deploying anything onto my Kubernetes cluster.

Is there an option for that outside of creating a custom script?

Comment: how are you collecting logs from Kubernetes?

Comment: I'm taking the output of `kubectl --kubeconfig $kubeconfig logs $pod_name -c $container --since=10m` and sending it up to datadog for each container in each pod in the cluster.

Comment: does your kubernetes cluster support sidecar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way would be to use a sidecar container with a logging agent, it won't increase the load on the API server.

[image]

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-a-logging-agent

Datadog agent looks like doesn't support /suggest running as a sidecar (https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/2203#issuecomment-416180642)

I suggest looking at using other logging agent and pointing the backend to datadog.

Some options are:

- fluentd: https://blog.powerupcloud.com/kubernetes-pod-management-using-fluentd-as-a-sidecar-container-and-prestop-lifecycle-hook-part-iv-428b5f4f7fc7
- fluentd-bit: https://github.com/leahnp/fluentbit-sidecar
- filebeat: https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat

Datadog supports them

- https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/fluentd/
- https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/filebeat/